# Stop Fb from Autopost on Group Wall after creating a new Event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating a new Event on A FB Group using the Graph API.........I am adding Title,Date,Location,Photo and Description...............When it is successful,fb adds it to event tab.........this is all fine..........

Now,FB also automatically add it to group wall with only title,date,location.........I want to show description too here.........and don't want it twice........

So,I have two ways here

1) Fb somewhere allows to add description here on the group wall post..

2) I can prevent FB to autopost on group wall on creation of new event and I invoke another post using Graph API......which will allow me to add description........

Also,it will work if I am able to delete this auto-created post on wall........

FB Experts,any suggestion much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You could try if the `no_feed_story` parameter that is documented for creating events for pages works for group events as well.

Comment: no_feed_story is not working......